# How do form this sentence "I want (object) to (verb/be) that..." in Chinese?

Tags: simplified-characters, sentence-structure

I want (object) to (verb/be) that...

For examples :

- I want you to know that you are not alone anymore
- I want her to be my wife
- I want my brother to help me with my homework
- I want you to be mine

Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

我想要(object)(verb/be)……

e.g.

- 我想要你知道你不再孤独
- 我想要她成为我的妻子
- 我想要我哥哥帮我做作业
- 我想要你成为我的